# system("bcdedit /set safeboot") does not set windows to safeboot

Tags: c++, cmd, 32bit-64bit, bcdedit

Here is the c++ code with command, command for run windows in safeboot with network mode and restart, This code run only in 32 bit operating system but in 64 bit only restart will happen but not in safeboot mode.

[NOTE] : I run application in administrative mode.

```
system("bcdedit /set safeboot network  > Out.txt");
system("shutdown -r -f -t 0");
```

and also with `ShellExecute()`

```
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/C bcdedit /set safeboot network > Out.txt", 0, SW_HIDE);
ShellExecute(0, L"open", L"cmd.exe", L"/C shutdown -r -f -t 0 > Out.txt", 0, SW_HIDE);
```

I tried manually like Open CMD in administrative mode

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /set safeboot network
The Operation completed successfully.
c:\WINDOWS\system32>shutdown -r -f -t 0
```

Manually it was working (run in safeboot) but when I tried through code Windows restarted, but not in safeboot.

> How to make this work both 32 bit and 64 bit operating system ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run your program with the system() call as an administrator? I would not expect that call to succeed if you do not.

Answer (score 0):

`> Out.txt` are probably not valid arguments Note that system is not a command shell interpreter to redirect standard io. If you want to get output then it would be better idea to redirect them manually using CreateProcess or some wrapper such as boost.Process.

Answer (score 0):

Am executing the program on a `64` bit machine. The `bcdedit.exe` file exists in `C:\Windows\System32` Although `C:\Windows\System32` is in system path, in an `x86` process are subject to the [File System Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx). Which means that `C:\Windows\System32` actually resolves to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

There is no `32` bit version of bcdedit.exe in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

The solution is to change target `AnyCPU` or `x64.`